Voltage Response of Simply Driven RC Circuit
Can anyone explain why the first equation is wrong and the second correct?
I have always liked doing circuit analysis in the past and now, I came back to doing it for fun.
I have always used where the current comes in the + signal in the potential but reviewing capacitors using the Razavi lectures, he arrived to the second equation in this circuit (after t=0) and I don't understand why.

The image is based on YouTube video - Razavi Basic Circuits Lec 18 at 30:00. He came up with the second equation. I came up with the first equation.
$$I = C_1\frac{\partial V_{out}}{\partial t}$$
$$(1)\;V_1 = R_1C_1\frac{\partial V_{out}}{\partial t} + V_{out}$$
$$(2)\;-V_1 = V_{out} + R_1C_1\frac{\partial V_{out}}{\partial t}$$

Who said the first is right and the second is wrong?

I formatted the equations, which were otherwise difficult to read on small screens like phones.

In the video at 30:00, I see above the lecturer's head your equation 1.

$$V_1 =R_1C_1\frac{\partial V_{out}}{\partial t} + V_{out}$$
which I believe to be correct.
I do not see your equation 2, which you claim is in the video, although I did not watch the whole lecture. You wrote:

He came up with the second equation. I came up with the first equation.


He corrected it at the end so he gets -t/RC, he will change it to R1C1(∂Vout/∂t) = -Vout - V1

@Derteck do you know the timestamp where he "corrects" the equation? The "correction" is wrong, anyway.

Yeah I just realized that because of your answer, when he changed the signals he corrected it wrongly. Do I still leave the question?

My response has been up-voted, so I don't believe you can delete the question now.

ahh okay thank you then. Maybe someone gets stuck and it helps!

Yes, it may be useful (or not :-))
